# How to give permission to record video in DU Recorder app?

Tags: permissions, video

Can someone tell me how can I enable this permission that is being asked in the screenshot below?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: "I tried everything" ? We don't know what you tried. Please let us know so as to avoid redundant answers.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings, Apps, and then find your app. Inside there should be a list of permissions. Enable the ones that are disabled.

Comment: I tried but there no such a thing on my phone! My phone is Huawei P8 Lite!!

Comment: @Adem Go to Settings - Apps & Notifications - Apps, then find the app in question that is trying to record video and tap on it, then select Permissions and make sure they are all enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Disable "Display over apps" for the DU Recorder app from the phone settings. That worked for me.

[image]